# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, string-formatting, typeerror

So I am VERY new to programming and I started with Python 3. I started reading "Learn Python the Hard Way". Now, I got to a point where I had this code:

```
x = "There are %d types of people." % 10
binary = "binary"
do_not = "don't"
y = "Those who know %s and those who %s" % (binary, do_not)

print(x)
print(y)
print("I said: %r") % x
```

I do not really know the difference between `%r`, `%s` and `%d`. The error I get is `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'` No idea what to do and how to fix it. Please explain how I can actually make it work and why it won't work. Also, what is the difference between %r,d and s? Any useful links? Thank you in advance.

Comment: why the downvote? this is a new user, let's not chase him/her away without an explanation.

Comment: @markg I guess because the question is very poor and it is trivial to find this kind of thing out.

Comment: @markg because the error tells the OP precisely what the problem is?

Comment: I find the new style formatting more readable and intuitive. `'I said {}'.format(x)`. Then you can do, for example, `{:.2f}` to print a number rounded to two decimal places.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it does, if you know Python. For a very beginner, it is not so easy to read (but probably achievable, if one bangs their heads against it enough time).

Comment: @juanchopanza why can't this be the place they find it out?

Comment: @markg Because this is not the kind of place for that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @jonrsharpe the error is only intuitive if you have experience interperting it

Comment: this reminds me of when i first joined this platform, a team of well of 12 will visit my question and mark it as unconstructive, un-this un-that and leave. no direction, no assistance, no explanation. so i stopped asking.

Answer (score 21):

You want to apply `%` to the *string* instead:

```
print("I said: %r" % x)
```

Your code is applying it to the return value of the `print()` call, which returns `None`.

Alternatively, you can switch to using [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print("I said: {!r}".format(x))
```

Answer (score 19):

You are calling the `%` outside of the `print()` function. This tries to see if the actual function `print` can be printed as `%r`, and because `print` doesn't return anything, it tries to get `%r` for the value `None` (hence the `NoneType` error). Change it to:

```
print("I said: %r" %(x))
```

The following code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
x = "Hello"
print ("Hello World! %s") %(x)
```

Raises the following error:

```
Hello World! %s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in 
    print ("Hello World! %s") %(x)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Changing the code to the following works:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
x = "Hello"
print ("Hello World! %s" %(x))
```

Output:

```
Hello World! Hello
```